# When I echo !!! 0 it gives me a strange result

Tags: php

I understand why "echo !0;" returns 1. What I don't understand is why  echo !!!0 also Returns 1. Please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: try echo !!!!!0 for a bit of repetitive fun.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you think `!0` results in `1`? Because if you understood this correctly the reason for `!!!0` also being `1` should be pretty obvious.

Comment: well Im saying echo not false so it returns a one meaning true so why does !!! also returns a one

Answer (score 6):

You're missing that `!` is the *not* operator, and that `0` is a falsy value:

```
!0;//oposite of "false" ==> true ==> 1
!!!0;//oposite of the oposite of the oposite ==> oposite
```

When a boolean is echoed, it's converted to its actual value (if any). For something to be true, it has to be. So `true` is `1`. Likewise, for something to be false, it can't be, so `echo false;` shows as an empty string, as deceze pointed out.
To be absolutely clear, you should think of `!!!0` as some childish attempt at _"reverse psychology".

```
Don't give nothing to me. ~=> Give something to me (Don't + nothing is double negation)
I'm not Not giving nothing to you. ~=> I'm not giving anything (not + not + nothing is tripple negation)
```

Bottom line, assume `n` is the number of `!` signs preceding a value/var/expression, which we'll call `e`:

```
if n%2 === 0
   (n(!)) e === (boolean)e
if n%2 === 1
   (n(!)) e === !e
```

IF the number of negation operators preceding the operand is even, the expression will be evaluated to the its value, cast to a boolean value. If the number of negation operators is odd, the expression will be evaluated to its oposite boolean value.
Just replace all `!`'s with *the oposite of*.

Comment: `false` is actually `""`, not `"0"` when cast to a string.

Comment: @deceze: yest and `"" == 0 == false`, but not `"" === 0 === false`

Comment: Yeah, sure; but I'm not talking about comparison rules, I'm talking about `echo false` !== `"0"`.

Comment: @deceze: Right you are. Corrected my answer

Comment: thanx i get it guys kinda knew it just had to be sure

Comment: @user2674150: You're welcome. I hope you don't mind my asking to accept the answer that best explained what you wanted to know? That's the SO way of saying thanks. If you do, there's a +2 rep bonus in it for you

Answer (score 2):

It is `echo` that actually failed you, Never use this operator when doing some research.
But make a habit of using `var_dump()` instead:

```
var_dump(!0);
```

and you will always know the real value:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 1):

`!0` is equal to `true;`

and when you echo true you get `1`

Zero by itself is considered false:

```
if (0) // false
   echo "you won't see this."

if (!0) // if not 0 means true
   echo "you see this."
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `!` is the logical NOT operator and 0 is interpreted as `false`, you get this:

```
!0 -> true
!!0 -> !(!0) -> !(true) -> false
!!!0 -> !(!(!0)) -> !(!(true)) -> !(false) -> true
```

When you `echo true;`, PHP outputs a `1`.

Comment: You failed with proper explanation too. If you make it even dozen transmutations, !0 won't be 1 anyway.

Comment: You're right, [it will be true](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). Which is output as 1. But how about answering or giving the correct explanation instead of downvoting everybody?

Comment: You got a downvote because you provided the wrong answer, that's why downvoting is here for. It's not a quality information. I upvoted you because you fixed your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`!` is the logical NOT operator. Changes the boolean value to the opposite value  0 <=> 1

0 = 0

!0 = 1

!!0 = 0 (second ! change to 1 and the first change the 1 into 0)

!!!0 = 1

Comment: !0 is not actually equal to 1

Comment: Talking strictly a logical system is a binary system since there are only two possible values (true and false).